# No se muestran los items del recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo el recyclerview creado y lo muestro a través del adapter, viewmodel e interactor.
Mi problema es que cada vez que se crea la Activity no muestra el recyclerview.
He estado investigando y la única manera de que se muestre el recyclerview es cambiando el telefono de modo claro a modo oscuro o al revés.
No es problema de que no se vea con el modo claro o con el oscuro, si inicio la actividad en modo oscuro tengo que cambiarlo a modo claro para poder verlo y al revés.
Es como si al cambiar de modo activara el recyclerview y no entiendo porqué pasa esto, he trabajado con recyclerview durante un montón de tiempo y nunca me había pasado. También he probado a hacer un proyecto nuevo desde otro ordenador por si acaso la hubiera liado en el manifest o en el Themes, pero no se que es lo que puede causar esto.

> Muestro como relleno el rv

**Adapter**

```
class EmocionAdapter (private var listener: OnClickListener):
    ListAdapter<EmocionEntity, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(EmocionDiffCallback()){

    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        mContext = parent.context

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_emocion, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val emocion = getItem(position)

        with(holder as ViewHolder) {
            setListener(emocion)

            binding.tvEmocion.text = emocion.emocion

            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(emocion.imagen)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(binding.imgEmocion)

        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val binding = ItemEmocionBinding.bind(view)

        fun setListener(emocionEntity: EmocionEntity) {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onClick(emocionEntity)
            }
        }
    }


    class EmocionDiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<EmocionEntity>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: EmocionEntity, newItem: EmocionEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: EmocionEntity, newItem: EmocionEntity): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class EmocionViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var intetactor: EmocionInteractor = EmocionInteractor()
    private var emocionSelected = MutableLiveData<EmocionEntity>()

    private val emociones: MutableLiveData<MutableList<EmocionEntity>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<MutableList<EmocionEntity>>().also {
            loadEmociones()
        }
    }

    private fun loadEmociones() {
        intetactor.getEmociones {
            emociones.value = it
        }
    }

    fun getEmociones(): LiveData<MutableList<EmocionEntity>> {
        return emociones
    }

    fun setEventSelected(emocionEntity: EmocionEntity) {
        emocionSelected.value = emocionEntity
    }

    fun getEventSelected(): LiveData<EmocionEntity> {
        return emocionSelected
    }

}
```

**Interactor**

```
class EmocionInteractor {

    fun getEmociones(callback: (MutableList<EmocionEntity>) -> Unit) {
        val url = Constants.URL + Constants.GET_EMOCIONES

        var emocionesList = mutableListOf<EmocionEntity>()
        val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, { response ->

            val mutableListType = object : TypeToken<MutableList<EmocionEntity>>() {}.type
            emocionesList =
                Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), mutableListType)

            callback(emocionesList)
            return@JsonArrayRequest
        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
            callback(emocionesList)
        })

        EmocionesApplication.emocionesAPI.addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest)
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

> Donde relleno la información

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var emocionAdapter: EmocionAdapter
    private lateinit var gridLayoutManagerEmociones: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var emocionViewModel: EmocionViewModel

    companion object{
        const val MY_CHANEL_ID = "MyChanel"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        emocionViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[EmocionViewModel::class.java]

        loadRecyclerView()
        setupViewModel()

        createChanel()

        binding.imgEmpresa.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo)

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(EmocionesApplication.actualUser.imagen)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(binding.icUser)

    }

    private fun loadRecyclerView() {
        emocionAdapter = EmocionAdapter(this)
        gridLayoutManagerEmociones = GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.recyclerview.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = gridLayoutManagerEmociones
            adapter = emocionAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        emocionViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[EmocionViewModel::class.java]
        emocionViewModel.getEmociones().observe(this) { emociones ->
            emocionAdapter.submitList(emociones)
        }
    }

    private fun scheduleNotification() {

        val tiempoActualReal = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmNotification::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tiempoActualReal + 86400000, pendingIntent)
    }

    fun createChanel(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                MY_CHANEL_ID,
                "MySuperChannel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply{
                description = "EMOCIONES"
            }

            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(emocionEntity: EmocionEntity) {
        //scheduleNotification()
        val intent = Intent(this, EmocionDialogueActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("id", emocionEntity.id)

        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

> Lo de notification es para que mande notificación al usuario para que entre todos los días y ponga como se siente

> También pongo los layout

**Item emoción**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEmocion"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvEmocion"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmocion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/emocion"
            android:visibility="visible"
            style="@style/SubtitleMcv1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Layout main activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEmpresa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvIcUser"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:elevation="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icUser"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEmpresa"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_emocion"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> También le puse visibility=visible porque pensé, no vaya a ser por esta tontería

Comment: Creo que deberías cargar el código del Activity y el recyclerview

Comment: En consonancia con lo que te comenta @Mateo. Si, como dices, el RV se carga al cambiar de modo, agrega a la pregunta el fragmento de código que maneja los cambios de modo claro a modo oscuro, así como el código del Fragment o Activity en el que llenas el RV. No creo que sea un problema del Manifest o de los Temas, es un problema en la lógica de tu programa. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano listo, eso les ayudaría?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en qué parte de tu código se gestiona el cambio del modo claro al modo oscuro y viceversa? Dices que sólo entonces se llena el RV, pero no veo nada relativo a eso en tu código. Te aconsejo que cuando algo falle pongas puntos de interrupción en las diferentes partes, así podrás ir revisando el estado de los objetos cuando depures la aplicación. Algo que me parece extraño es que estás observando el ViewModel, pero no veo que llames en ningún momento al método que debería empezar a obtener los datos, que será, tratando de adivinar tu lógica `loadEmociones()`

Comment: Es decir, en el método `setupViewModel()` de `MainActivity`, luego de esta declaración: `emocionViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[EmocionViewModel::class.java]` deberías tener algo así: `emocionViewModel.loadEmociones()` Insisto, tratando de adivinar la lógica de tu programa. El hecho es que antes de observar con `emocionViewModel.getEmociones().observe(this) { ...` tiene que haber algo qué observar.